# Time for clearing controls at Taipei International airport

Tags: airports, taipei

I will soon take an outbound flight from Taipei Taoyuan International airport with Scoot.

The airport site advices to reach the airport 2-3 hours before the flight departure. For various reason I cannot reach the airport so early, and I am wondering what is the actual time for clearing controls and if I really need 2-3 advance, considering that:

- I am not a Taiwanese citizen, so will need to go through outbound immigration controls (if present)
- I will only carry hand luggage, no check in luggage

Comment: Like in most airports, it probably depends a lot on date and time.

Comment: Are you referring to Taoyuan airport (TPE)? or Songshan airport (TSA)?

Comment: I haven't been to Taipei in about 5 years but last time I was there, it had the longest security line I have ever seen. It  overflew from the security area into the main terminal for hundreds of meters taking up more than half of the terminal floor space.  By my estimate there were about 2000-3000 people in a single line. This being said, I did arrive early (3 hours maybe), it moved reasonably fast and I did make my flight